# log hazard function in R

Tags: r, survival, lognormal-distribution, hazard, function

I'm trying to write out the log hazard function of the lognormal distribution and use this in R.

Using the survival function:

[image]

and the hazard function:

[image]

I have the following for the log(hazard):

log(hazard) = $-\log(2\pi)/2-\log(\sigma)-\log(t) - ((\log(t)-\mu)^2)/(2\sigma^2) - \log(1-\phi((\log(t)-\mu)/\sigma))$

In R I think this should be:

```
log(hazard) = -0.5*log(2*pi)-log(sigma)-log(t) - 
               ((log(t)-mu)^2)/(2*sigma^2) - 
               log(1-pnorm(log(t),mu,sigma))
```

Can anyone confirm whether this is the correct syntax to use?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How do you estimate the parameters using the log hazard? You probably want to maximise the log-likelihood instead, I guess...

Comment: @ocram: why are you convinced that they want to estimate the parameters with the log hazard?

Answer (score 2):

I *think* that's right. But I'm not going into to really check the details because it's unnecessary. It's much easier to calculate the log hazard *directly from the definition*. In other words,

```
logNormLogHaz <- function(x, mu, s){
    dens_vals <- dnorm(x, mu, s)
    s_vals <- 1 - pnorm(x, mu, s)
    logHazs <- log(dens_vals) - log(s_vals)
    ## More numerically stable then
    ## logHazs <- log(dens_vals/s_vals) *I think*
    return(logHazs)
}
```

And if you have a very good reason for explicitly writing it out as you have, you can at least use the above function to check that your new function is correct.

Comment: Just to provide more details - I want to use this log hazard function to be able to estimate the parameters mu and s. When I attempt this, my value for mu is almost identical to that obtained when fitting the lognormal aftreg/survreg survival equation, but my estimate for sigma is slightly out, so I didn't know if there was an error somewhere.